# Append selected after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a Select 2 drop down search function. I am trying to load the results from an ajax call as the selected/default values. I am not sure where I am going wrong? What is the syntax I need to change here so that when I click my modal it shows results preset.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editApptModal-button').click(function() {
    var appointmentID = $(this).attr('data-appointmentID');

    $('#editApptModal').find('input[name="appointmentID"]').val(appointmentID);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'ajax',
      method: 'get',
      url: '/ajax',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

        $.each(response.employees.data, function(key, value) {
          $('select').append($("<option selected></option>",
            //<HERE Selected is not working. 
            //If I remove selected results load in dropdown
            {
              value: value.id,
              text: value.name
            }));
        });

        $('#editApptModal').modal('show');
      },
      error: function(response) {
        alert('Could not displaying data' + response);
      }
    });

    $('#editApptModal').modal('show');
  });
});

<select multiple="multiple" name="employees[]" id="form-field-select-4" class="form-control search-select"> 
<option selected value=""></option>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but adding several 'selected' options can break your select if it's not a multiple select ?

Comment: It is a multiple select. I have added it onto question.

Answer (score 1):

First you should try to append only once because it's an heavy operation.
And by setting attributes directly seems to work here.

```js
var datas = [
  {value: 'toto', text: 'Toto'},
  {value: 'titi', text: 'Titi'}
];

var options = '';
$.each(datas, function(key, value) {
  options += '<option selected>'+value.text+'</option>';
});

$('#select').append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple id="select"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to issue the refresh command after you are done. Here a quick snippet of it working doing the same thing for one of my projects. TransportRecord_TransportCarrierID is the ID for my select element.

```
                $('#TransportRecord_TransportCarrierID').empty();
                $.each(jsonResponse, function (key, item) {
                    var option = $('<option selected>').text(item.Text).val(item.Value);
                    $('#TransportRecord_TransportCarrierID').append(option);
                });
                $('#TransportRecord_TransportCarrierID').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Html

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-defaultWhite" multiple="multiple" id="TransportRecord_TransportCarrierID" name="TransportRecord.TransportCarrierID">//your initial options</select>
```